# Rounding in SQL - inconsistent results for one query?

Tags: sql, oracle

Is there any possibility that depending on environment or other circumstances rounding result according to this SQL formula:

```
ROUND(2.85*23/100,2)
```

would return sometimes: 0.66, 0.65 or 0.6600 or is it determined to always return 0.66 ?

Comment: This expression should always return the same value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL*Plus; `set numformat` affects the result. For example:

```
SQL> set numformat 9.99
SQL> select round(2.85*23/100, 2) from dual;

ROUND(2.85*23/100,2)
--------------------
                 .66

SQL> set numformat 9.9999
SQL> select round(2.85*23/100, 2) from dual;

ROUND(2.85*23/100,2)
--------------------
               .6600

SQL> set numformat 000G00D0
SQL> select round(2.85*23/100, 2) from dual;

ROUND(2.85*23/100,2)
--------------------
            000.00,7

SQL>
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer - but is there any possibility to make it 0.65 based on a setting?

Comment: You're welcome. As far as I can tell, **no**, because the result of that operation is 0.6555. It is **ROUND** that makes it 0.66 so all you can do is to affect that result (0.66).